# Filtering Emails By Domain Names

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say I have two arrays -

```
$EmailList1 = array("abc@domain1.com", "def@domain2.com", "ghi@domain3.com");
$EmailList2 = array("jkl@domain1.com", "mno@domain4.com", "pqr@domain5.com");
```

Now I'd like my new array to be **[mno@domain4.com, pqr@domain5.com]**

The reason **jkl@domain1.com** was omitted because it has domain *(domain1.com)* which already is present in `$EmailList1`

My approach would be to first get all the domains of `$EmailList1`, storing it into an array, looping through each item of `$EmailList2` and then getting the result.

Is this the right way or there could be a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is

```
$EmailList1 = array("abc@domain1.com","def@domain2.com","ghi@domain3.com");
$EmailList2 = array("jkl@domain1.com","mno@domain4.com","pqr@domain5.com");

$diff = array_udiff($EmailList2, $EmailList1, function ($a, $b) {
    return strstr($a, '@') === strstr($b, '@') ? 0 : 1;
});

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($diff);
```

Output

```
array (size=2)
  1 => string 'mno@domain4.com' (length=15)
  2 => string 'pqr@domain5.com' (length=15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$uniqueEmailsArray = array_unique(array_merge($EmailList1 , $EmailList2));
```

Comment: You just want to keep the values from the second array and dump the values from the first ?

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
<?php
$EmailList1 = array("abc@domain1.com", "def@domain2.com", "ghi@domain3.com");
$EmailList2 = array("jkl@domain1.com", "mno@domain4.com", "pqr@domain5.com");

foreach($EmailList1 as $email){
  $emailArray = explode('@',$email);
  $domainArray[] = $emailArray[1];
}

$domains = array_unique($domainArray);

foreach($EmailList2 as $email){
  $emailArray = explode('@',$email);
  if(!in_array($emailArray[1], $domains) && !array_search($emailArray[1], $domains)){
    $sorted_emails[] = $email;
  }
}

print_r($sorted_emails);
?>
```